# How to manage form state using both redux and react in multi steps form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a react multistep form project(checkout steps). When user click on certain step(e.g. gift wrapping section), the redux state will display true, if click on the other steps' form, the state will be false. I use this to control whether or not to show the detail info on the certain page. For example, when user goes to the next step and go back to the page, if user typed in the gift info previously, the input fields will be assigned the value from the redux store into .

When user stays on the certain page, they will be able to edit and save the form successfully, (I use redux to create the edit and save function and save the gift info into an object). However, when the user goes to the next step and click back to the certain page, the page seems to re render a new form and the redux store still saves the info that I previously saved, but when I edit and save the data, the whole info will be saved as a new object that apply a new edit and save function from redux, so the store array will contains duplicate object.

I'd like to ask what will be a better solution for this situation?

```
onClickBack() {
    const { currentStep } = this.state;
    if (currentStep === 0) {
      this.setState({ showback: false});
    } else {
      if (currentStep === 3) {
        if(this.props.contacts != null){
          this.props.showDetail(); // state turns to true on step 3
        }
      } else {
        this.props.hideDetail();
      }
    }
  }
```

global click back function

```
saveGiftOption(e, index) {
      this.setState({ showhidedetail: !this.state.showhidedetail });
        e.preventDefault();
        let cartamount = 0;
        cartamount = parseInt(this.state.boxvalue.substring(1));
        let msg = {}; // the whole object will be saved into the redux array
        msg = {
            id: this.props.item.id,
            itemName: this.props.item.name,
            giftmessagevalue: this.state.giftmessagevalue,
            boxvalue: this.state.boxvalue,
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            phone: this.state.phone,
            address: this.state.address,
            cartamount: cartamount,
        }
        Promise.all([
            this.props.addReducer(msg, index) // save action
        ]).then(() => {
            let payload = 0;
            payload = msg.cartamount;
            this.props.sumTotal(payload);
            this.props.sumArrayTotal(payload);
        });
    }

editGiftOption(e, index){
    this.setState({ showhidedetail: !this.state.showhidedetail });
    e.preventDefault();
    Promise.all([
        this.props.clearReducer(index) // clear action
    ]).then(() => {
        this.props.counter.counter -= this.props.counter.arr[index];
        this.props.clearTotal(index);
    });
}
```

save and click function on the step 3 form

```
switch (action.type) {
    case TYPE_ADD: // addReducer
      return [...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.msg)]
    case TYPE_CLEAR: // clearReducer
      return state.filter((data, i) => i !== action.id);
    default:
      return state
  }
```

add and edit reducer

```
contacts: [
    { id: '0c29c778', itemName: 'A item', giftmessagevalue: 'thankyou', ... },
    { id: '189377ad', itemName: 'B item', giftmessagevalue: 'test', ... },
    { id: '0c29c778', itemName: 'A item', giftmessagevalue: 'thankyou', ... },
    { id: '189377ad', itemName: 'B item', giftmessagevalue: 'test', ...}]
// first 2 object created when user stays on the certain page
// last 2 object created when user go to the next page  and go back to the certain page and edit the form
```

Comment: The best method in my opinion is to do things with the "react final form" package. As redux is not the place you should store information if another location is avaialbel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is using redux-form (https://redux-form.com/) to manage the form state in redux. It allows saving the managed form states in the redux store. If the user switches between forms, the forms can be reinitialized using the saved information.

Generally speaking, the issue here is that the state is not restored/set correctly. The reducer part to add items doesn't work as expected:

return [...state,
Object.assign({}, action.msg)]

You can see, [{id: "aa"}, {id: "aa"}] cannot be merged into [{id: "aa"}] since they are different objects.

Comment: keep in mind that react-redux-form specifically says not to use it and to use react-final-form

Comment: sure, it depends on the project. If it is a new project, I'd recommend final form as well ;)

Comment: @Alexander Hemming Thanks for providing the suggestion, I'll look into the redux-form and the redux-final form package.

Comment: @motou Yes, I think the problem is that if switching between forms, the array will store all the new object in it without noticing that there are duplicate object in it.